# Error creating heatmap with segmentBy but no trendBy

Tags: gooddata

I'm playing around with the [heatmap](https://sdk.gooddata.com/gooddata-ui/docs/heatmap_component.html) component using the `@gooddata/react-components` version `5.3.0`.  For the most part, everything works as expected.  However, I'm running into one issue.

The analytical designer allows me to design a heatmap with either only rows, or only columns.  I can render a heatmap using the SDK with only columns by specifying the `trendBy` property with no `segmentBy` property.

However, when I try to render a heatmap with only rows by specifying the `segmentBy` property with no `trendBy` property, I get the following error message:

```
ERROR TypeError: "viewByAttribute is undefined"
  generateStackedDimensions
  getResultSpec
  getStackingResultSpec
  Heatmap
  _constructComponentWithoutOwner
  measureLifeCyclePerf
  _constructComponentWithoutOwner
  _constructComponent
  mountComponent
  mountComponent
  performInitialMount
  mountComponent
  mountComponent
  mountComponentIntoNode
```

Here are the props I'm using to create the component:

```
{
  "projectId": "gzgbtigdh6iva4r8m56ht7i0s7dezb4i",
  "config": {
    "legend": {
      "enabled": true,
      "position": "bottom"
    }
  },
  "sdk": {
    ...
  },
  "drillableItems": [
    ...
  ],
  "measure": {
    "measure": {
      "localIdentifier": "3a155bf79d0f4adaa3a7f00a59633c0c",
      "title": "Constituent actions",
      "definition": {
        "measureDefinition": {
          "item": {
            "uri": "/gdc/md/gzgbtigdh6iva4r8m56ht7i0s7dezb4i/obj/5996"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "segmentBy": {
    "visualizationAttribute": {
      "localIdentifier": "33bec35eab9b43a1a9fd33dc28360cbd",
      "displayForm": {
        "uri": "/gdc/md/gzgbtigdh6iva4r8m56ht7i0s7dezb4i/obj/33684"
      }
    }
  },
  "filters": [
    {
      "relativeDateFilter": {
        "dataSet": {
          "uri": "/gdc/md/gzgbtigdh6iva4r8m56ht7i0s7dezb4i/obj/1186"
        },
        "granularity": "GDC.time.month",
        "from": -11,
        "to": 0
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Is there an issue with the way that I'm specifying my props for this component?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

thank you for your question. It is a bug in Heatmap implementation. We will fix it in few next days and release patch version of `@gooddata/react-components` package
Please use just the working "only column" configuration for now. Thx and sorry for any inconvenience

**UPDATE:**
we released fixed version yesterday - 5.3.1